# Try to get two images to resize according to page width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two images that I am pulling from a JSON file. Both images scale down accordingly depending on the screen width when the browser is resized, but on page load the initial image doesn't show until the page is resized. Hope someone can help below is my code:

```js
(function() {
  
  'use strict';

     var url = 'path to json';
    
     $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
     
   var sliderImage = '';
   var categoryImage = '';
   
   $.each(json[0], function (i, item) {
    sliderImage += '<img src="' + item.imageSliderURL + '">';
    categoryImage += '<img src="' + item.imageCategoryURL + '">';
      });
  
   $(window).resize(function() {
   
   if ($(this).width() >= 800) {
       $('#recipeSlider').html(sliderImage);
    } else if ($(this).width() <= 800) {
       $('#recipeSlider').html(categoryImage);
   }
     });
   
   });
 })();
```

```html
 <div id="recipeSlider"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer.

```
 (function() {

 'use strict';

 var url = 'path to json';

 $.getJSON(url, function(json) {

     var sliderImage = '';
     var categoryImage = '';

     $.each(json[0], function (i, item) {
         sliderImage += '<img src="' + item.imageSliderURL + '">';
         categoryImage += '<img src="' + item.imageCategoryURL + '">';
     });
     function funLoadImage(){

        if ($(window).width() >= 800) {
            $('#recipeSlider').html(sliderImage);
        } else {
            $('#recipeSlider').html(categoryImage);
        }
     }

     funLoadImage();
     $(window).resize(funLoadImage);

  });
  })();
```

The problem with your code was it's not assigning image to element when page is loaded for first time.

Comment: this works but initially on page load its pulling the smaller image. once then its resized it takes the larger image

Comment: @Tom this is probably related to how the function uses "this". Try changing to `$(window).width` instead of `$(this).width`

Comment: Downvoted: This doesn't account for the page / images being loaded when it calls `funLoadImage` inside getJSON. It may not work on a server.

Comment: @Hal50000 function scope does matter when it gets called. Hence it will work on server also.If we want to call same `funLoadImage` from any other function then we have to change it's scope.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are adding image only on `window.resize`:

Do like this:

```
(function() {

     'use strict';

     var url = 'path to json';

     $.getJSON(url, function(json) {

         var sliderImage = '';
         var categoryImage = '';

         $.each(json[0], function (i, item) {
             sliderImage += '<img src="' + item.imageSliderURL + '">';
             categoryImage += '<img src="' + item.imageCategoryURL + '">';
             //Make sure images are added on load
             $('#recipeSlider').html(sliderImage).promise().done(function(){
 $('#recipeSlider').html(categoryImage);
```

});

```
         });


         $(window).resize(function() {

            if ($(this).width() >= 800) {
                $('#recipeSlider').html(sliderImage);
            } else if ($(this).width() <= 800) {
                $('#recipeSlider').html(categoryImage);
            }
         });

      });
 })();
```

Comment: This removes the resize portion all together which isn't the desired result. They want different images when the screen gets small enough.

Comment: @MattiPrice He isn't getting images on load because he isn't adding them at all on load. Images are being added only on resize event trigger. Updated Answer, Though.

Comment: thanks guys. trying gschambial's code...it works except the first image that initially loads is the smaller image. any idea how i can correct that? the slider image is 2000x500 and the category image(smaller one) is 800x500

Comment: @Tom I have updated the answer. Check it out. You can add a promise to `html` method of first image and the second image will be loaded only after first image loading is done.

Comment: @gschambial I'm aware of why he isn't getting the image, I was pointing  out that your code broke his desired results.

Comment: @gschambial it still defaults to the smaller image

Answer (score 0):

You aren't injecting an image until you resize it. So on page load no image is displayed. You can either add a default image inside your "recipeSlider" div, or you can add a function called on page load that adds the image.

You should refactor your code so that the portion that chooses the image is in it's own function. Call that function on page load and page resize and you should have the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

Without resizing they never get added to the html of you #recipeSlider div because you are using `$(window).resize(function() {`

Something like this would initialize things.

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
if (windowWidth >= 800) {
  $('#recipeSlider').html(sliderImage);
} else if (windowWidth <= 800) {
  $('#recipeSlider').html(categoryImage);
}
```

However I would recommend merging this and your resize function into another function that you can use initially and on resize

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate function for the resize. Then call it on both ready and resize events.

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    // some code removed for clarity

   $(window).resize(function() {
       resizeImages();
   });


    $(window).ready(function() {
          resizeImages();
    });


 })();

function resizeImages () {
    if ($(this).width() >= 800) {
        $('#recipeSlider').html(sliderImage);
    } else if ($(this).width() <= 800) {
        $('#recipeSlider').html(categoryImage);
    }
}
```